# Compatible and incompatible devices with apk

Tags: android, apk

Is there any way to know which devices are compatible and which incompatible with an apk before publishing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. After uploading an apk, you will see a screen like below, if not it can be found on your [Developer console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) and then clicking into the app in question and then the `APK` tab.

If you upload a new apk you will see

[image]

Clicking `Save draft` will save the apk but not release it to the public. You will then see the following:

[image]

In the `APK` tab, there should be a box called `Supported devices`, with a link `See list`. Clicking on that should bring up a window that shows the following:

[image]

In the window you can see a list of `all devices`, `all supported/unsupported devices` and a list of `manually excluded` devices.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering the question.

What you are saying is once the apk is published to production? I mean, this version will be available on google play, and that is what I wanted to avoid.

I have found a solution, uploading the apk for alpha testing as it is shown in your image, so I can upload it and follow the proccess you said but without making the update available on google play.

Thank you.

Comment: You can upload an apk without publishing it. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Jany I have updated my answer, to show how it can be done without uploading the apk to the alpha testing section.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, much better than using the alpha method. Thanks!